# Hide Submit Button Until Successful Upload

Tags: android, iphone, appcelerator

Hi I'm new to Appcelerator and I need a bit of help with an app I'm working on. The app contains a form with a View where images can be take from the camera or selected from the gallery. This View has two buttons. The first button is to upload the image and the second button is to submit the form. I want to see if someone can help modify the code so I can hide the submit button until the image has successfully uploaded. Thanks in advance for your help. Here is the code I'm using:

```
var win = Ti.UI.createView({
    width : Ti.UI.FILL,
    height : Ti.UI.SIZE,
    top : 20,
    title : L('header_title'),
});

var topbar = Ti.UI.createView({
    width : Ti.UI.FILL,
    height : 50,
    top : 0,
    title : L('header_title'),
    backgroundImage : Ti.Filesystem.resourcesDirectory + "image/topbar.png",
});

var back_btn = Ti.UI.createButton({
    width : 80,
    height : 30,
    title : "Customer",
    backgroundImage : Ti.Filesystem.resourcesDirectory + "image/button_image.png",
    left : 5,
    top : 10,
    font : {
        fontSize : 12
    },
});

var home_btn = Ti.UI.createButton({
    width : 60,
    height : 30,
    title : "Home",
    backgroundImage : Ti.Filesystem.resourcesDirectory + "image/button.png",
    right : 5,
    top : 10,
    font : {
        fontSize : 12
    },

});
back_btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    self.close();

});

home_btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var Window;
    Window = require('ui/handheld/ApplicationWindow');
    new Window().open();
});

var header_title = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    color : 'white',
    font : {
        fontSize : 22
    },
    text : 'Forms',
    textAlign : Ti.UI.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER,
    top : 10,
    width : Ti.UI.SIZE,
    height : Ti.UI.SIZE
});

topbar.add(header_title);
topbar.add(back_btn);
topbar.add(home_btn);
win.add(topbar);

var scroll = Ti.UI.createScrollView({
    width : Ti.UI.FILL,
    height : Ti.UI.FILL,
    top : "10%",
    contentHeight : 420,
    right : '2%',
    left : '3%',
});

var submit_img1 = Ti.UI.createImageView({
    width : 100,
    height : 100,
    top : 10,
    left : 10,
    backgroundDisabledColor : true,
});

var submit_btn1 = Ti.UI.createButton({
    width : 100,
    height : 30,
    top : 120,
    left : 10,
    font : {
        fontSize : 14
    },      
    backgroundImage : Ti.Filesystem.resourcesDirectory + "image/button.png",
    title : 'Image1',
});


var basicSwitch = Ti.UI.createSwitch({
    top : 330,
    value : true,
    left : -100,
    width : 100
});

basicSwitch.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    Ti.API.info('Switch value: ' + basicSwitch.value);

});

var upload_btn = Ti.UI.createButton({
    width : 100,
    height : 30,
    top : 330,
    right : 100,
    font : {
        fontSize : 14
    },      
    backgroundImage : Ti.Filesystem.resourcesDirectory + "image/button.png",
    title : 'Upload First',
});

var SubmitForm_btn = Ti.UI.createButton({
    width : Ti.UI.FILL,
    height : 30,
    top : 380,
    right : 10,
    left : 10,
    font : {
        fontSize : 14
    },
    backgroundImage : Ti.Filesystem.resourcesDirectory + "image/button.png",
    title : 'Submit Form',
    enable : 'false',
});

var style;
if (Ti.Platform.name === 'iPhone OS'){
  style = Ti.UI.iPhone.ActivityIndicatorStyle.DARK;
}
else {
  style = Ti.UI.ActivityIndicatorStyle.DARK;
}
activityIndicator = Ti.UI.createActivityIndicator({
  color: 'black',
  font: {fontFamily:'Helvetica Neue', fontSize:26, fontWeight:'bold'},
  message: 'Loading...',
  style:style,
  top:'35%',
  left:"25%",
  height:Ti.UI.SIZE,
  width:Ti.UI.SIZE
});

//image Uploding --Image 1
submit_btn1.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

    ///For Option dialog
    var sourceSelect1 = Titanium.UI.createOptionDialog({
        options : [L('Take Picture'), L('Choose Existing'), L('Cancel')],
        cancel : 2
    });
    sourceSelect1.show();
    sourceSelect1.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        Ti.App.pic = Ti.App.Properties.getInt('pic');
        if (e.index === 0) {//Camera
            Titanium.Media.showCamera({
                success : function(e) {
                    var image = e.media.imageAsResized(e.media.width / 2, e.media.height / 2);
                    if (e.mediaType == Ti.Media.MEDIA_TYPE_PHOTO) {
                        Ti.App.Properties.setInt('pic', Ti.App.pic + 1);
                        Ti.App.pic = Ti.App.Properties.getInt('pic');
                        var picFileName = 'pic' + Ti.App.pic + '.png';
                        submit_img1.image = image;
                        image_value[0] = e.image;
                        image1_flag = true;
                        totalCount++;
                    }
                },
                error : function(error) {
                    if (error.code == Titanium.Media.NO_CAMERA) {
                        alert(L('no_camera'));
                    }
                },
                saveToPhotoGallery : true,
                allowEditing : true,
                mediaTypes : [Ti.Media.MEDIA_TYPE_PHOTO]
            });
        } else if (e.index === 1) {//PhotoCallery
            Ti.Media.openPhotoGallery({
                success : function(e) {
                    var image = e.media.imageAsResized(e.media.width / 2, e.media.height / 2);
                    if (e.mediaType == Ti.Media.MEDIA_TYPE_PHOTO) {
                        Ti.App.Properties.setInt('pic', Ti.App.pic + 1);
                        Ti.App.pic = Ti.App.Properties.getInt('pic');
                        var picFileName = 'pic' + Ti.App.pic + '.png';
                        submit_img1.image = image;
                        image_value[0] = e.image;
                        image1_flag = true
                        totalCount++;
                    }
                },
                error : function(error) {
                    alert(error.code)
                },
                allowEditing : false,
                mediaTypes : [Ti.Media.MEDIA_TYPE_PHOTO]
            });
        }
    });
});

var ind = Titanium.UI.createProgressBar({
    width : 200,
    height : 50,
    min : 0,
    max : 1,
    value : 0,
    style : Titanium.UI.iPhone.ProgressBarStyle.PLAIN,
    top : 200,
    message : 'Uploading Image',
    font : {
        fontSize : 12,
        fontWeight : 'bold'
    },
    color : '#888'
});

upload_btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

    pb.show();

    for(var i=0; i<=7; i++ ) {

        count_image =i+1;
        UploadPhotoToServer(count_image);

    }
});

var createReq = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();
SubmitForm_btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

activityIndicator.show();
Ti.API.info('Form Submitting');

var sender = Ti.App.Properties.getString('Sender');
var phone = Ti.App.Properties.getString('Phone');
var nts = Ti.App.Properties.getString('Notes');     
var email = Ti.App.Properties.getString('Email');

var st;
Ti.API.info('Switech state:' +basicSwitch.value);

if(basicSwitch.value==true)
{
    st='1';
}
else
{
    st='0';
}


if (Ti.Network.online == false) {
    var alertDL = Ti.UI.createAlertDialog({
        title : L('connection_error_title'),
        message : L('connection_error_msg'),
        buttonNames : ['OK']
    });
    alertDL.show();
} else {

var sender = Ti.App.Properties.getString('Sender');
var phone = Ti.App.Properties.getString('Phone');
var nts = Ti.App.Properties.getString('Notes');     
var email = Ti.App.Properties.getString('Email');

var params = {
//Server : Titanium
sender : sender,
phone : phone,
notes: nts,             
email : email,
enlist:st,
images:finalName,
Action:"coming_from_iphone"
};

//First View

console.log(params);
createReq.open("POST", 'http://www.mysite.com/ajax1.php');
createReq.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
createReq.send(params);

createReq.onload = function() {

    Ti.API.info('res@loginReq.onload:\n' + this.responseText);
    //alert(this.responseText);

    var Window;

    Window = require('ui/handheld/ApplicationWindow');

    new Window().open();

}

    createReq.onerror = function(e) {
        //Ti.App.fireEvent('server_error_msg');
        var alertDL = Ti.UI.createAlertDialog({
            title : L('error'),
            message : L('server_error_msg'),
            buttonNames : ['OK']
        });
        alertDL.show();
    }
}

});

var pb=Titanium.UI.createProgressBar({
    top:'50%',
    width:250,
    height:'auto',
    min:0,
    max:80,
    value:0,
    color:'#fff',
    message:'Image Uploading....',

    font:{fontSize:14, fontWeight:'bold'},
    style:Titanium.UI.iPhone.ProgressBarStyle.PLAIN,
});
function UploadPhotoToServer(args) {

Ti.API.info('Image Nimber:',args);
if (Titanium.Network.online == true) {

    var xhr = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
// On lo
    xhr.onerror = function(e) {
        Ti.API.info('IN ERROR ' + e.error);
        alert('Sorry, we could not upload your photo! Please try again.');
    };

    xhr.onload = function() {
    //alert(this.responseText);

    Ti.API.info('Final Name'+this.responseText);
    if(name_count ==0)
    {
        var res=this.responseText;
        finalName+=res;
        name_count++;
        Ti.API.info('Final Name'+finalName);
    }
    else
    {
        var res=this.responseText;
        finalName+=","+res;
        name_count++;

        //finalName =String(finalName ,+ this.responseText());
        name_count++;

        Ti.API.info('Final Name'+finalName);
    }
    // alert(finalName);        

    if (count_upload <= 70) {
            var s=80;


            count_upload += s/totalCount;
            pb.value= count_upload;

            if (count_upload == 80) {

                pb.hide();
            }
        } else {
            pb.hide();
        };
        Ti.API.info('Response From Server:'+this.responseText);
        Ti.API.info('IN ONLOAD ' + this.responseText + " " + this.status + ' readyState ' + this.readyState);

    };

    xhr.onsendstream = function(e) {
        Ti.API.info('ONSENDSTREAM - PROGRESS: ' + e.progress);
        if (Ti.Platform.osname == 'android') {
            //android doesn't support the "progress" variable during onsendstream yet :(
            //we're going to dummy up a progress value for this based on each packet being about 2.5% of the total upload progress
            //it won't be totally accurate, but it will give the user a good indicator that the upload is working
            if (androidUploadProgress < 1) {
                androidUploadProgress += 0.025;
            }
        } else {
            //else on ios devices, calculate the progress of the upload using e.progress
            if (Math.round(e.progress * 100) <= 100)
             {

            //pb.value+=1.0;

            }
            else
            {
                //pb.hide();
            }
        }
    };
    xhr.open('POST', 'http://www.mysite.com/ajax1.php?Action=upload_image');


        if (args==1)
             {
                if (image1_flag == true)
                {
                    xhr.send({
                        userfile : submit_img1.image,
                });
                }
                else
                {
                    //alert('no image');
                }
             };
    } 

    else {
        alert('You must have a valid Internet connection in order to upload this photo.');
    }
}

function createRandomString (argument) 
{
    var text = "";
    var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

    for( var i=0; i < 20; i++ ) {
        text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
    }
    return text;
}
scroll.add(submit_btn1);
scroll.add(submit_img1);
scroll.add(basicSwitch);
scroll.add(upload_btn);
scroll.add(SubmitForm_btn);

win.add(scroll);

self.add(win);
win.add(activityIndicator);
win.add(pb);

win.add(ind);

return self;
```

Comment: accepted my answer. click tick mark and you also get reputation

Answer (score 1):

```
 Titanium.App.addEventListener('hideButton', function(e) {
            yourButton.hide();
        });
```

call like

```
Titanium.App.fireEvent('hideButton');
```

Answer (score -1):

When you are uploading set

```
Button button.setEnable(false);
```

After it completed

```
button.setEnable(true);
```